# Problem closing MDI child window in Terminal Services/Remote Desktop Connection 7.0

Tags: remote-desktop, remote, windows-terminal-services

I have one user whose computer just got updated to the 7.0 Remote Desktop Connection.  Concurrently, she has started having a problem closing the MDI child windows in an old FoxPro application running on the remote server.

- We have two different servers, both 2003, running the same application, one locally and one at a remote office.  Only the remote office server is giving trouble.
- It works fine for me, even when logging into her TS account.  No other users have complained.
- The other day the same user experienced an error message (path not found for a path showing a localization placeholder) starting the RDC, fixed by reboot.  I suspect she may have had RDC running during the 7.0 upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User had two desktop icons for the application on the terminal server; one from All Users and one in her local profile.  The All Users icon was pointing to the incorrect path (direct-local, whereas it is usually accessed via mapped drive)

I'm still left without a *why*, but at least it's working.